# Shortening grep Command to 80 Characters Bash

Tags: bash, grep, newline, ifs

I am writing a Bash script and have some really long grep commands that I want to shorten to 80 characters for better style. Here is one I am working with now

```
omR_pdisk="omreport storage pdisk controller=0";
${omR_pdisk} vdisk="$vdisk_id" | grep ^Vendor ID | sed 's,.* : ,,g' >> "$results"
```

I need to get that second line down to 80 characters. I have tried a few things so far but I keep getting errors. I tried the following

```
${omR_pdisk} vdisk="$vdisk_id" | 
grep ^Vendor ID | 
sed 's,.* : ,,g' >> "$results"
```

And I tried this

```
${omR_pdisk} vdisk="$vdisk_id" \
| grep ^Vendor ID \
| sed 's,.* : ,,g' >> "$results"
```

I also tried

```
getVendorID="grep ^Vendor ID | sed 's,.* : ,,g'"
${omR_pdisk} vdisk="$vdisk_id" | "$getVendorID" >> "$results"
```

None of these are working. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The first one should work; lines ending with `|` are continued automatically.

Comment: As should the second one, since it is the same as the first, just with explicit line continuations. The third fails because the quoted value of `$getVendorID`is treated as a command *name*, not a fragment of shell code to execute.

Comment: Also, note that the call to `grep` is unnecessary: `... | sed '/^Vendor ID/s,.* : ,,g'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can break a command line with a back slash, but you must insert some operator that indicates a continuation first. For example this should work:

```
${omR_pdisk} vdisk="$vdisk_id" | \
    grep ^Vendor ID | \
    sed 's,.* : ,,g' >> "$results"
```

(At least the syntax. Don't know what the code actually does.)

Comment: A command cannot end with a `|`, so line continuation is automatic when the line ends with one. That is, the backslash is unnecessary.

Comment: This is true for current versions of bash (just reproduced with 4.2), but I could swear that this hasn't always been the case. Unfortunately can't reproduce, though.

Comment: As far as I know, it's specified by POSIX (or at least, it works in `dash` as well).